# why is system.web not available?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, system.web

looking to use :

```
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Synchroniser/ConvertXML/App.config");
```

in my project. .HttpContext is flagging as namespace does not exist.
I have looked at an old project where this works and have imported the same ref file to my references, but it is flagging with a yellow explainataion mark, also tried adding

```
    using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
```

but no joy, any idea?

Comment: `Project/References/Add reference`

Comment: i tried adding the it through there but it wasnt showing, so i browsed for it in a different project and it imported but is flagging as yellow

Comment: Have you perhaps downgraded your target framework version?

Comment: He might be targeting the .NET Client Profile, which will not include that particular assembly. Make sure to target the full .NET framework.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your project is targeting the full .NET 4.0 instead of the Client Profile:

[image]

Now, you need to add a reference to the `System.Web` assembly and `using System.Web` to the file:

[image]

All this being said, please note that it's an absolutely abominable thing to do. Your class libraries (a.k.a DAL, BAL, whatever ...) should have strictly no knowledge about any HttpContext. That's purely web stuff and should live only where it belongs - to the web tier.

Your DAL, BAL, ... should not be doing any `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` calls. It should simply be taking the filename as parameter. The way this filename is calculated is purely the responsibility of the caller. So if the caller is a web application it could use the `MapPath` method. If the caller is a desktop application it should use something else. If it is a Windows Phone application it should use another thing. See how now your DAL, BAL, ... is agnostic of the caller and far more reusable?

Comment: True, just a small note - there's no point in adding a `using System.Web` if he wants to use a fully specified name including the namespaces... Just wanted to clarify this for the OP, cause it seems he thought that adding an additional using at the top of the file might resolve the issue.

Comment: The whole point of my answer is that he shouldn't be doing anything like that. He shouldn't be using any `HttpContext` in places where he is not supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath should be replaced by HostingEnvironment.MapPath and ref System.Web.Hosting to avoid using httpcontext